failed to connect the Dbeaver and db2
I don't know which step went wrong, causing the final connection to fail. Please help me solve the problem if you have experience
When I click on "test connection" button. It pop up this information to inform me some errors occured.
Error
SqlException
com.ibm.db2 jcc.am.SqlException

Does the target database already exist?  What is your connection string?  Please try a different tool, especially DbVisualiser because that tool automatically reports better error messages than Dbeaver.  You can also an an extra option to you existing connection string in DBeaver to tell it to collect better textual error messages and error details when it gets an exception. The option is retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;   (  DbVisualizer adds this automatically for Db2, but DBeaver does not, so the dbeaver messages have no text).
